# MVC, model having knowledge of other models, or ADOs having knowledge of other ADOs

Tags: oop, model-view-controller

Man I'm in the weeds here, both learning OO principles AND learning MVC practices...
Hopefully I can convey my question accurately. These aren't specifics, but generally how I have some things organized - my question is HOW do I organize, and communicate between processes.HOW do you represent JOINED data AND how do you insert/update...

My Data Layer (tables)

```
PERSON, ADDRESS(relates to personID), PHONE(relates to personID)
```

So a person can have multiple addresses, or multiple phones....

My Model is

```
PERSON - which uses an ADO to get and put data into data layer (id,name)
ADDRESS - which uses an ADO to get and put data into data layer (id, personID, address)
PHONE - which uses an ADO to get and put data into data layer (id, personID, phone)
```

My View may have multiple PHONE fields, or ADDRESS fields - but I guess the principle isn't the issue - MY issue is what 'talks' to what and when....

Here's what I'm thinking:
the VIEW will call the PERSON controller with a PUT, the controller will call the PERSON model which will do the PERSON insert, and return the ID, the controller will then call the ADDRESS controller (or model?????), then THAT id comes back. the PERSON controller will then call the PHONE controller (or model?????)...

Is that the way it's suppose to work?
OR (like the title asks) should the MODELs communicate?

OR (like the title asks) should the ADOs to the talking among themselves? the entire form submit get passed to the PERSON controller, which hands it off the the PERSON model -  the MODEL knows address and phone need ADDRESS ADO, and PHONE ADO respectively.. so INSIDE the person.put() method, the insert is made to all three...

What's the correct OO way of decoupling???

Thx - I know this is a bit more theory and less specific code - but I need to know how Im gonna code it before I break it. either way will work - it just 'feels' weird both ways because I'm not used to thinking like this yet. What am I looking for?

Comment: You have an entity HUMAN with attributes PERSON (demographic data), PHONE and ADDRESS contact information. The controller manages the HUMAN and controls access to the combined entity.

Comment: @Bob, I appreciate the desire to help me abstract out a schema, however my sticking point isn't with that aspect. I still have the question of how to insert to multiple data points - I presume, each with their own "model" - it's the joined data that presents as a single view and how THAT get's managed by the MVC. thx.  - if I read you correctly my FIRST thought is the correct one... the PERSON controller handles all the interaction,.... thx

Comment: It's easy enough to use the PERSON controller to handle everything. I think I may have missed something in your question. Are you using an ORM? Or are you rolling your own?

Comment: Then you have to take a step backwards and look not at an object but an object graph. The object graph consists of all of those objects that are related to each other. The PERSON, as the parent ADO, should be "talking" to the ADDRESS and PHONE ADOs to get and set their respective values.

Comment: ok, so NOT the controller OR the model but the data transport layer (regardless of what I call it) should presume knowledge of dependencies, or do I have to pass them in? - SO Vies calls Controller (person) and PERSON Controller calls PERSON Model, which does whatever logic needs, then passes Obj to ADO (Data transfer layer) and the PERSON ADO calls the ADDRESS ADO, and PHONE ADO and does it's inserts/ID returns/FK inserts and returns whatever...to the PERSON Model... CORRECT?

Comment: That's one approach that would work. You could partition the ADOs into high level and low level parts where the high level PERSON ADO calls the low level ADOs for PERSON, ADDRESS and PHONE. The high level part knows about the object graph, namely PK/FK management; the low level part knows about select/update/create/delete.

Comment: If you're going to go that route - what's wrong with letting the model handle that management? just the idea of decoupling the data layer structure from the model? In my mind having the PERSON ADO pass back the ID, or "knowing" its avail to pass with the needed data to the OTHER ADOs seems like a wash and no 'real' knowledge of the structure is needed by the model except things it already need to know to pass and receive data....